# How to filter object list with LINQ without using nested If statement

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two LINQ queries with different order by filters. I want to avoid using a nested `If` statement.

My current aproach is:

```
If (userlist.count > 0) Then
    If (Filter()) Then
        users = From u In userlist Order By (If(u.name ) username,1,0) 
                descending u.name ascending 
    Else
        users = From u In userlist
                Select u.name Distinct Order By u.name Ascending
    End If
Else
    users = New List(Of String)
End If
```

Comment: Use a ternary operator? It will look quite messy however... Perhaps create a function to handle Linq query. It would then be reasonably tidy.

Comment: Your code has a bunch of errors from what I can tell - the If( without 3 arguments, the mysterious username reference after the If(),  the select before the Order By in the second From, the different data types of users in the then and else parts of the nested if ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just want to avoid nesting if statements.
You can achieve this by using a function and leaving the function with Return as soon as a condition is valid.

```
Function GetUserNames(userList As List(Of UserList), username As String)
    If (userList Is Nothing OrElse Not userList.Any()) Then
        Return New List(Of String)
    End If

    If Filter() Then
        Return From u In userList Order By (If(u.Name = username, 1, 0)) Descending, u.Name Ascending
    End If

    Return From u In userList
           Select u.Name Distinct
           Order By Name Descending
End Function
```

Notice you don't have nested if statements and actually you don't need the else part as well.

Also take advantage of linq by building the statement. Assume that the Distinct name should be applied for both queries:

```
    Dim query = userList.Select(Function(u) u.Name).Distinct

    If Filter() Then
        Return query.OrderByDescending(Function(n) If(n = username, 1, 0)).ThenBy(Function(n) n)
    End If

    Return query.OrderBy(Function(n) n)
```

-- update --

The bounty asks for '.. an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.'. That's why I've included a link to an article of Martin Fowler, where this design is described:

https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `Select Case` statements in the `Sort` or `OrderBy` part of my LINQ queries, as it's much easier to read:

```
Select Case search.Sort
    Case "Name"
        OutputList = OutputList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name).ToList()

    Case "-Name"
        OutputList = OutputList.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Name).ToList()

    Case "Date"
        OutputList = OutputList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.[Date]).ToList()

    Case "-Date"
        OutputList = OutputList.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.[Date]).ToList()

    Case "Percent"
        OutputList = OutputList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.CompletedPercentage).ToList()

    Case "-Percent"
        OutputList = OutputList.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.CompletedPercentage).ToList()

End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I interpreted your code correctly, why not remove all the If statements?

```
    Dim sortUsername = If(Filter(), "", username)
    users = (From u In userlist Order By If(u.name > sortUsername, 1, 0) Descending, u.name Ascending Select u.name Distinct).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a let keyword within LINQ and have a variable which will be used in making decisions.